# undefined from arrValue.start_date

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get from my database the start_date and end_date, however, I am getting "undefined" in console from arrValue.start_date or arrValue.(x) regardless of input.

```
        unavailabletimes = [];
        is_conflict = false

        $.ajax({
          url: '<%= preload_parking_path(@parking) %>',
          dataTyp: 'json',
          success: function(data) {

            $.each(data, function(arrID, arrValue){
              unavailabletimes.push([moment(moment.utc(arrValue.start_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')), moment(moment.utc(arrValue.end_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'))] );
              console.log(arrValue.start_date);
                })


              var prestart_date = $('#reservation_start_date').datetimepicker('viewDate');
              var start_date = moment(moment(prestart_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
              var preend_date = $('#reservation_end_date').datetimepicker('viewDate');
              var end_date = moment(moment(preend_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));

              if(end_date.diff(start_date, 'minutes') < 60){
                var duration = 60;
              }else{
                if((end_date.diff(start_date, 'minutes') % 60) == 0){
                  var duration = end_date.diff(start_date, 'minutes');
                }else{
                  var duration = ((end_date.diff(start_date, 'minutes') - (end_date.diff(start_date, 'minutes') % 60)) + 60);
                }
              }

              unavailabletimes.forEach((unavailabletime)=> {
                // unavailabletime = [moment, moment]
                // check with start time and end time
                if (start_date <= unavailabletime[0] && end_date >= unavailabletime[1]) {
                  is_conflict = true
                }
              });

              if(is_conflict) {
                $('#message').text("Cannot overlap existing bookings!");
                $('#preview').hide();
                $('#btn_book').attr('disabled', true);
              } else {
                var total = duration/60 * <%= @parking.price %>;
                $('#message').text("");
                $('#preview').show();
                $('#btn_book').attr('disabled', false);
                $('#reservation_hours').text(duration/60);
                $('#reservation_total').text(total);

              }
        }

      });
```

arrValue on itself works and it returns the database entries but adding the .(x) i.e start_date or end_date.

[This is my console for arrValue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoQ0q.png)

What could be the cause of this? What I am trying to do is setup a booking system that does not allow overlapped booking down to the hour. I am trying to retrieve the time interval between start_date and end_date. Push it into unavailabletimes to find conflict. I am new to coding so I apologize if its a little messy.

Comment: several issues but start with spelling `dataTyp: `

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss fixed that but it doesn't seem like its the cause of the issue.

Comment: From this post, there is no way for us to tell.  Put `success: function(data) {
console.log(data);` or if it fails put in a failure on the `$.ajax().fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
    });` - and then add that to your question as information we can work with.

Comment: if it IS a date, you might have to parse whatever was returned https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#:~:text=The%20Date.,not%20recommended%20to%20use%20Date.

Comment: FWIW, I never click on links in a question since the site requires all information IN the question in case that link ever goes dead.

Comment: I found the problem using your method above. data was returning 3 arrays: reservation, unavailabledates, and specialdates. The last two were empty so .start_date would cause it to be undefined. I changed it to $.each(data.reservation, function(arrID, arrValue), and that fixed the issue. Thanks for your help! as for the link, I wanted to attach and image of my console but it pasted a link. Noted for the future! thanks.